# Visual Studio Code, Windows, Git client (Version 2.20.1) can't push code to GitHub 503 error

Tags: git, github, networking

Pushing to GitHub when connected to the corporate network fails. However, I can fetch on the corporate network. I can also push to GitHub when not connected to the corporate network.

When I try to push the code across the network I get...

error: RPC failed; HTTP 503 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 503 Service Unavailable

What I have tried...

Increase size of the buffer

```
git.config --global http.postBuffer 35728640
```

Even added extra zeros to that to the point where I got an out of memory error, which was expected when setting it so high.

Tried to use the Windows cert store, rather than openssl.

```
git.config --global http.sslBackend schannel
```

I was getting a certificate revocation list error, setting this fixed that.

```
git.config --global http.schannel.checkrevoke false
git.config --global http.sslVerify "false"
```

Also tried

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Then...

```
git gc --aggressive --prune
```

I also created a fresh clone for kicks. Same result.

Are there any other config tricks to try? The network team is looking at the network, but so far they have not noticed anything unusual. Apparently, there is no proxy server.

I noticed that the intermediate certificates for GitHub are not in the Windows trust store, but if I am not verifying SSL certs, that should not matter, since it is working fine when not connected to the corporate network on the same machine.

Odd fact, I'm in MD, Corporate is in Illinois. I wonder if there would be a way to test just individual GitHub nodes/availability zones.